# Factorization of $\exp(A+B)$ for non-commuting operators $A$ and $B$

Tags: matrices, exponential-function, quantum-mechanics, matrix-exponential

I am trying to understand the following expression

$$\exp(A+B) = \exp(A/2) \exp(B) \exp(A/2) + O((A,B)^3)$$

where $A$ and $B$ are in general non-commuting operators. The formula appears in the following link as a variant of the [Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula) formula:

- Y. D. Chong, [The split-step Fourier method](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Mathematical_Physics_and_Pedagogy/Computational_Physics_(Chong)/11%3A_Discrete_Fourier_Transforms/11.03%3A_The_Split-Step_Fourier_Method), April 30, 2021.

I would like to have a proof of the expression and to know how to figure out if the approximation is a good one given $A$ and $B$, so that I can understand the method in the link. I have no clue how to prove this. The only clue I have is the [Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula) formula, but I cant see the relation between them (saying it is a variant may not even mean that you can get the later from the BCH, i don't know).

Comment: Hello Rodrigo. I don't have any clue on another reference. I found the formula in the site provided and the author makes no comment on the validity of it. I think it may be implicit in the $O(A,B)^3$ error estimation, but I don't even understand what (A, B) is. It seems powers of A and B (or both). I completely clueless. Before posting the question I tried to find a derivation in the internet. No lucky.

Comment: I assumed this may be standard notation. Also, I assumed this would be something simple to prove. So I thought the problem was me, and my lack of knowledge on the topic. something on that way. But I think his explanation on the method is the clearest I found, apart this formula of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dual to the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula is the [Zassenhaus formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#Zassenhaus_formula)
$$ e^{A + B} = e^A e^B e^{-\frac{1}{2}[A, B]} \dots.$$
Using this on $A + B = A/2 + (B + A/2)$ twice, we get
$$ \begin{align*}
e^{A + B} &= e^{A/2} e^{B + A/2} e^{-1/2[A/2, B+A/2]} \dots \\
&= e^{A/2} e^B e^{A/2} e^{-\frac{1}{2} [B,A/2]} e^{-1/2[A/2, B+A/2]} \dots
\end{align*} $$
Looking at the terms with commutators at the end, we have
$$
-\frac{1}{2} \Bigl( \frac{B A}{2} - \frac{A B}{2} \Bigr) - \frac{1}{2} \Bigl( \frac{A B}{2} + \frac{A^2}{4} - \frac{B A}{2} - \frac{A^2}{4} \Bigr) = 0. 
$$
Hence there are no "second order" terms when we use this symmetric arrangement of $A + B = A/2 + B + A/2$. Of course there are still third order terms I haven't bothered writing out, involving things like $[A/2, [B+A/2, A/2]]$ and similar. Presumably the author of the text uses $(A, B)^3$ as some kind of abbreviation for terms of that shape.

Comment: Your comment on the abbreviation makes sense to me now! But given those terms are weird commutators, how can I know, given A and B, the approximation is good? In the site the author gives the two operators. But how can I know the approximation is valid?